# What actually happens when AJAX calls a different encoding page?

Tags: php, ajax, character-encoding

Assuming my page is UTF-8 encoded, and my code calls `a.php` where `a.php` is fetched through ajax (jQuery) `$.get` and the file called has a different encoding like `windows-1255` specified in the header?
What is happening behind the scenes?
Thanks

Comment: good question. my experience is the browser seamlessly translates the characters to unicode for internal use(and so all documents are capable of using the entire unicode character set regardless of what character set is implied by the encoding declared), but i would love to see someone answer this in detail. I'm assuming all characters can map into the unicode char set, which im not sure about.

Comment: also, maybe edit your question to clarify that the declared encoding of the other page is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Well, everything is just bytes until a web browser interprets them and translates them into characters to present for the user. So it doesn't really matter what happens in AJAX, as there will exist an encoding conflict anyway.

For example, if AJAX returns the Scandinavian character 'å' encoded as UTF-8, it is encoded with the two bytes 0xc3a5. Now, if the web browser expects the encoding to be UTF-8, then they will be rendered as an 'å' to the user, no problem. However, if the web browser expects, say, Latin1, they will essentially be interpreted as two characters, namely 0xc3 and 0xa5, which happen to represent the characters Ã¥.

Comment: Is there a way to change the way the data brought from ajax is shown?

Comment: The best solution is always to work with the same encoding, however, this is not always plausable, in which case you will have to know the encoding of both ends and then convert one to the other. There are probably libraries for this, which is where my knowledge stops.